# Unable to fetch values with indexof function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am unable to find out what I am doing wrong code looks fine to me but I am unable to get the Log.

Here is a glimpse of my code:

```js
function getempinfo() {
  var xmail = 'sachin';
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('19zdQSZFX7GTVvkUIDUErfJE7SdfxEw8dhtIkzv7mUOI');
  var sheet = ss2.getSheetByName('Employee');
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastrow, 16).getDisplayValues();

  var xmaillist = data.map(function(r) {
    return r[0];
  });

  var position = xmail.indexOf(xmaillist);

  if (position > -1) {
    return data[position];
  } else {
    return "Record Does not exist";
  }
  Logger.log(position)

}
```

Comment: Also if any of openById, getSheetByName or getRange are async, you need to run some callback

Comment: I havent posted the complete code and that is why function is not visible here let me change.

Comment: Imho, the IDE should mark the last line (and any linter should complain about it). Other than that, when looking over the code after a glass of water, and some fresh air, the issue of "unable to get the Log" should be obvious. If not, last but least, running over it with a debugger once would be the "aha"-moment. As such, i conclude, that no effort was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The script will never log anything, since the function returns before reaching that line (`return` ends current function execution). Put `Logger.log(position)` before the `if... else` statement if you want the position to be logged.
- You are using [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), and providing an array as a parameter (`xmaillist`). I guess what you want to use instead is [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (find the index in `xmaillist` where `xmail` is located). In this case, you would have to do this instead:

```js
var position = xmaillist.indexOf(xmail);
```

#### Reference:

- [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)
- [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)